# How to maintain image quality with FPDF and PHP?

Tags: php, image, fpdf

I'm using FPDF with PHP to add an image to a PDF. But the image quality in the PDF is much worse than the original image, as you can see here:

[image: Print screen from web page] [image: Print screen from PDF]

Relevant code:

```
$image_height = 40;
$image_width = 40;
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$start_x = $pdf->GetX();
$start_y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Image('./images/ds_pexeso_ros_0_17.jpg', $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), $image_height, $image_width); 
$pdf->Output("pexeso".date("Y-m-d"),"I");
```

The original image is 150x150 pixels.

Comment: I also have this problem, did you figure it out? Maybe I can ask it a different way... If an image is 100 pixels x 100 pixels, what is the FPDF width and height to use to ensure image scaling does not occur?

Comment: TCPDF is an alternative - although you probably don't want to hear that! You could try it to compare quality however in case it is not library related.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced the same problem in projects for customers.
Blurry pictures in a generated pdf document even with hires images.

It took me a couple of hours, but this is what worked for me.

I have a taken a look at the code and saw that there was a scale factor being set in the constructor of the pdf document:

```
//Scale factor
if($unit=='pt')
    $this->k=1;
elseif($unit=='mm')
    $this->k=72/25.4;
elseif($unit=='cm')
    $this->k=72/2.54;
elseif($unit=='in')
    $this->k=72;
else
    $this->Error('Incorrect unit: '.$unit);
```

The scalefactor is depending on the value given in the constructor of the pdf document:

```
function FPDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm',$format='A4')
```

The default is 'mm'. In most of my documents I initiate a pdf document like:

```
$pdf = new PDF('P');
```

This means that there will be a scalefactor of 72/25.4 = 2.83 used.
When I placed an image before I just used:

```
$this->Image('path/to/file', 0, 0);
```

This way I got the blurry images. 
It is also possible to give the width of the image in the command

```
$this->Image('path/to/file', 0, 0, 200); // for a image width 200
```

This gave me an image that was far too large. But - and here comes the trick - when you divide the real width by the scalefactor (in my case 2.83) and put this in this statement it gives a perfectly sharp image:

```
$this->Image('path/to/file', 0, 0, 71); // for a image width 200 / 2.83 = app 71
```

I hope this works for you too!

Comment: This solution only works for scaling down an image. Let's say the raw image is really high definition. Using this solution for 1:1 ratio (rawwidth:pdfwidth) will not do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be related to:

```
 $image_height = 40;
 $image_width = 40;
```

With these two instructions your are setting the dimensions the image will have in the pdf.

But if the original image is bigger than 40x40 the scaling of the image can cause quality problem.

So what i suggest:

- Do a correct resize of the image (php provides GD library). Resize it to 40x40. The GD function imagecopyresampled is your friend: resize and resample the image! Complete reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php
- Insert now the image in the pdf

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. The fact is that I want to maintain the original width and height (150x150 px). What values for $image_height and $image_width I should set to maintain original width and height?

Comment: Well if in your pdf you want the image 150x150 then change the first two lines of your file: with $image_height = 150; $image_width = 150;

Comment: The units used in fdpf are not clear to me. As it is said in manual, for example for width - Width of the image in the page. There are three cases:
    If the value is positive, it represents the width in user unit
    If the value is negative, the absolute value represents the horizontal resolution in dpi
    If the value is not specified or equal to zero, it is automatically calculated. I am not sure how to set my user unit to pixels or what resolution to use to acheive not scaling images. Tx.

Comment: I have set $pdf = new FPDF("P", "mm", "A4"); That way I have define the user unit to mm, and convert px to mm (150px corresponds to 39.6875). Still the image is of worse quality.

Comment: If simply $image_height = 150; $image_width = 150; $pdf = new FPDF(); ... ?

Comment: That way fpdf enlarge the picture to 150mmx150mm (with bad quality too)

Comment: Well I'am not sure that "150px corresponds to 39.6875" always works, maybe can depend on screen resolution or other properties... I would try to resize the with GD as described in my post until it fits the pdf and doesn't loose quality.

Comment: I guess image quality depends on your pdf DPI setting. For instance you couldn't have a good image quality inside a 72dip pdf because creating it the image will be reduced to 72dpi even it was 300dpi.

Answer (score 0):

FPDF with a statement like this to set the user unit to mm
$pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','Letter');

```
<?php 

    require_once('fpdf.php');
    $image_height = 40;
    $image_width = 40;
    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','Letter');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $start_x = $pdf->GetX();
    $start_y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->Image('./images/ds_pexeso_ros_0_17.jpg',$start_x+0,$start_y-2,40);
   $pdf->Output("pexeso".date("Y-m-d"),"I");
?>
```

FPDF made a very good looking result.